# Invalid Identifier for Department ID in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

The code seems to be fine but for some unexplained reason I cant insert the values into the table. I only want to insert specific values but its showing as invalid for some reason

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20),
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
    COMMISSION_PCT NUMBER(2,2),
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6),
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
);
```

Table is created and works as it should
Its when this gets added where it goes wrong:

```
INSERT INTO employee (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) 
VALUES(176, 'Taylor', 'SA_REP', 80);
```

Hope I can get an answer for this

Comment: You created a table `employees` and you are inserting into `employee` (without the final "s"). Are you sure the "invalid identifier" is `department_id`, and not `employee`? If so, then perhaps you already had a table `employee` in your schema (***different*** from the new one you just created, with a different name!) and the `insert` is trying to insert in that old table, but that old table doesn't have a `department_id` column. In any case, you probably want to insert `into employees` (with an "s" at the end).

Comment: Note though that after you fix this first (and obvious) error, you will run into more. You have several columns declared `not null`, but you don't provide default values for them and you didn't include them in `insert`, which means that the `insert` will attempt to insert `null` in these columns (such as `email` and `hire_date`), resulting in errors.

Comment: I am.... an idiot

Comment: So am I, and I know many more, so it's not worth bragging about it. :-)

Comment: I fixed it and added the values. I have another error however with this `INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) 
VALUES(176, 'Taylor', 'jasontaylor@gmail.com', 31-AUG-1999, 'SA_REP', 80);` Error says that column is not allowed here, so Im guessing theres something Im missing in this case

Comment: Do not insert dates as strings, use [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1). So the date should be `..., date '1999-08-31', ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you fixed "something" (as comments suggest), now it is about invalid date you're trying to insert. This is what you're doing (note how SQL*Plus points to exact place where error happened):

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees(
  2    employee_id,
  3    last_name,
  4    email,
  5    hire_date,
  6    job_id,
  7    department_id
  8  )VALUES(
  9    176,
 10    'Taylor',
 11    'jasontaylor@gmail.com',
 12    31-AUG-1999,
 13    'SA_REP',
 14    80
 15  );
  31-AUG-1999,
     *
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

See? You can't insert `31-AUG-1999`, literally. It *looks* as a date to us, humans, but - it is not. If you try to enclose it into single quotes, yet another - different - error:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees(
  2    employee_id,
  3    last_name,
  4    email,
  5    hire_date,
  6    job_id,
  7    department_id
  8  )VALUES(
  9    176,
 10    'Taylor',
 11    'jasontaylor@gmail.com',
 12    '31-AUG-1999',
 13    'SA_REP',
 14    80
 15  );
  '31-AUG-1999',
  *
ERROR at line 12:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected


SQL>
```

What's wrong with that? It is that my NLS settings don't recognize such a format. Oracle tried to implicitly convert a string (which is what `'31-AUG-1999'` is) to a valid DATE datatype value, but failed.

So, what to do? Take control over it! Specify a valid DATE value, for example using a date literal which always looks like `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees(
  2    employee_id,
  3    last_name,
  4    email,
  5    hire_date,
  6    job_id,
  7    department_id
  8  )VALUES(
  9    176,
 10    'Taylor',
 11    'jasontaylor@gmail.com',
 12    DATE '1999-08-31',
 13    'SA_REP',
 14    80
 15  );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Or, use the `TO_DATE` function:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees(
  2    employee_id,
  3    last_name,
  4    email,
  5    hire_date,
  6    job_id,
  7    department_id
  8  )VALUES(
  9    177,
 10    'Taylor',
 11    'jasontaylor@gmail.com',
 12    to_date('31.08.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
 13    'SA_REP',
 14    80
 15  );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Or, alter session and set NLS settings as you wanted, but that's not a good idea. You'd rather do as demonstrated earlier:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mon-yyyy-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'croatian';

Session altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO employees(
  2    employee_id,
  3    last_name,
  4    email,
  5    hire_date,
  6    job_id,
  7    department_id
  8  )VALUES(
  9    178,
 10    'Taylor',
 11    'jasontaylor@gmail.com',
 12    'kol-1999-31',
 13    'SA_REP',
 14    80
 15  );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose date values with comma:

```
INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)  
VALUES(176, 'Taylor', 'jasontaylor@gmail.com', '31-AUG-1999', 'SA_REP', 80);
```

see fiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/feb15f/1/0

Comment: Says now that a non numeric character was found where a numeric should be

Comment: @Laser based on the table structure you provided , it works , see fiddle in my answer

Comment: yeah I dont know what is happening. gives me an error in oracle developer

Comment: Not really, @eshirvana. You're inserting a **string** into a DATE datatype column.  Lucky you if Oracle manages to implicitly convert it to a valid DATE value. It does so on SQL Fiddle, but certainly fails in all my databases. Insert DATEs, not strings (use date literal, TO_DATE function, whatever you find appropriate).

Comment: @Littlefoot yeah good point , it can be date format